In finite abelian group, extend 2-cocycle from subgroup
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, $K\leq G$ a subgroup and $[\alpha] \in \operatorname{H}^2(K,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$. Is it always true that one can extend $\alpha$ to $G$, i.e. find $[\beta] \in \operatorname{H}^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ such that $\beta(k_1,k_2) = \alpha(k_1,k_2)$ for all $k_i \in K$?
In other words, is the restriction map
$$\operatorname{res}: \operatorname{H}^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times}) \longrightarrow \operatorname{H}^2(K,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$$
surjective? If yes, how can I prove it? If no, can you give me a counterexample?
Based on the questions
When can a 2-cocycle on a subgroup can be extended?
and
when is the restriction $\operatorname{H}^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times}) \rightarrow \operatorname{H}^2(K,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ surjective?, I would assume the answer lies somewhere in the inflation-restriction exact sequence, but I have not been able to piece things together myself.
Can I view the subgroup as a quotient $K\cong G/H$ and use the projection $G\rightarrow G/H$ to lift the 2-cocycle? In that case I would have to show somehow that it restricts to $\alpha$ again.
